# Trying to load images from local path fails after restart in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I am storing Images on the device with this code (Using Swift 1.2 / iOS 8)

```
func saveImageLocally(imageData:NSData!) -> String{
    let time =  NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(subDirForImage) as String
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dir) {
        var error: NSError?
        if !fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error) {
            println("Unable to create directory: \(error)")
            return ""
        }
    }

    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("spot\(Int(time)).png")

    imageData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    println(UIImage(contentsOfFile: path))
    return path
}
```

This works good, as I can see the image within the println as well as within the Finder, if I observe the filesystem of my simulator.

After I restart my App within the simulator (or iPhone, it's the same behavior) I try to read the image like this:

```
func loadImageFromLocalStore(path: String) -> UIImage{
    if(!path.isEmpty){
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        if(image != nil){
            return image!;
        }
    }
    return UIImage(named: "noImage.png")!
}
```

But here the image can't be fetched. It's always nil. But: The path hasn't changed plus I still see the image within the file system.

Comment: How do you create the path for `loadImageFromLocalStore()`? In particular, does the path contain exactly the same time stamp that was used when saving the image?

Comment: Yes, Within the first method, I return the path. This path will be stored within a local db. And this will also be used to read the file again..

Comment: What error do you get if you load the data with `NSData(contentsOfFile:, options:, error: )?

Comment: I've solved the problem. See my own answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, my problem was that I saved the fully path which seems to be wrong. It's better to just save the image-name.

This is now the save method

```
 func saveImageLocally(imageData:NSData!) -> String{
    let time =  NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(subDirForImage) as String

    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dir) {
        var error: NSError?
        if !fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error) {
            println("Unable to create directory: \(error)")
            return ""
        }
    }

    let pathToSaveImage = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("spot\(Int(time)).png")

    imageData.writeToFile(pathToSaveImage, atomically: true)

    return "spot\(Int(time)).png"
}
```

And this is the read method

```
func loadImageFromLocalStore(imageName: String) -> UIImage{
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(subDirForImage) as String

    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if(!path.isEmpty){
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        println(image);
        if(image != nil){
            return image!;
        }
    }

    return UIImage(named: "noImage.png")!
  }
```

Best
Christian

Comment: what is the value for subDirForImage?